# axis -1 in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am struggling to understand two things from below matrix (numpy arrays):

1. How can I deduce from the **np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=1)** function that there are 5 dimensions? I am struggling to conceptually understand the (5, 2, **5**) part. I see it as (rows, column numbers, dimensions).
2. What does axis = -1 really mean? How to understand it?

```
x = np.linspace(start=-10, stop=0, num=5, endpoint=True)

y = np.linspace(start=1, stop=10, num=5)



cart_indexing = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing="xy") # cartesian indexing

>> [array([[-10. ,  -7.5,  -5. ,  -2.5,   0. ],
        [-10. ,  -7.5,  -5. ,  -2.5,   0. ],
        [-10. ,  -7.5,  -5. ,  -2.5,   0. ],
        [-10. ,  -7.5,  -5. ,  -2.5,   0. ],
        [-10. ,  -7.5,  -5. ,  -2.5,   0. ]]),
 array([[ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ],
        [ 3.25,  3.25,  3.25,  3.25,  3.25],
        [ 5.5 ,  5.5 ,  5.5 ,  5.5 ,  5.5 ],
        [ 7.75,  7.75,  7.75,  7.75,  7.75],
        [10.  , 10.  , 10.  , 10.  , 10.  ]])]

np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=0)

>> array([[[-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ],
        [-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ],
        [-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ],
        [-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ],
        [-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ]],

       [[  1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ],
        [  3.25,   3.25,   3.25,   3.25,   3.25],
        [  5.5 ,   5.5 ,   5.5 ,   5.5 ,   5.5 ],
        [  7.75,   7.75,   7.75,   7.75,   7.75],
        [ 10.  ,  10.  ,  10.  ,  10.  ,  10.  ]]])


np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=1)


>> array([[[-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ],
        [  1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ,   1.  ]],

       [[-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ],
        [  3.25,   3.25,   3.25,   3.25,   3.25]],

       [[-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ],
        [  5.5 ,   5.5 ,   5.5 ,   5.5 ,   5.5 ]],

       [[-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ],
        [  7.75,   7.75,   7.75,   7.75,   7.75]],

       [[-10.  ,  -7.5 ,  -5.  ,  -2.5 ,   0.  ],
        [ 10.  ,  10.  ,  10.  ,  10.  ,  10.  ]]])

np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=1).shape

>> (5, 2, 5)

np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=-1)

>> array([[[-10.  ,   1.  ],
        [ -7.5 ,   1.  ],
        [ -5.  ,   1.  ],
        [ -2.5 ,   1.  ],
        [  0.  ,   1.  ]],

       [[-10.  ,   3.25],
        [ -7.5 ,   3.25],
        [ -5.  ,   3.25],
        [ -2.5 ,   3.25],
        [  0.  ,   3.25]],

       [[-10.  ,   5.5 ],
        [ -7.5 ,   5.5 ],
        [ -5.  ,   5.5 ],
        [ -2.5 ,   5.5 ],
        [  0.  ,   5.5 ]],

       [[-10.  ,   7.75],
        [ -7.5 ,   7.75],
        [ -5.  ,   7.75],
        [ -2.5 ,   7.75],
        [  0.  ,   7.75]],

       [[-10.  ,  10.  ],
        [ -7.5 ,  10.  ],
        [ -5.  ,  10.  ],
        [ -2.5 ,  10.  ],
        [  0.  ,  10.  ]]])


np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=-1).shape

>> (5, 5, 2)
```

Comment: There are not 5 dimensions.  There are 3 dimensions (5, 2, 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by

> there are 5 dimensions

None of your arrays have 5 dimensions. You start with a list of 2 arrays with 2 dimensions;

```
for i in cart_indexing:
    print(f"Shape:{i.shape}; Dimensions:{i.ndim}")

Shape:(5, 5); Dimensions:2
Shape:(5, 5); Dimensions:2
```

Notice here how you have 5 and 5 and 2.

Then, the axis parameter in your stack comes into play:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(f"Stacked on axis {i} my array has {np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=i).ndim} dimensions and a shape of {np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=i).shape}")

Stacked on axis 0 my array has 3 dimensions and a shape of (2, 5, 5) #the 2 is in the (axis=)0th position
Stacked on axis 1 my array has 3 dimensions and a shape of (5, 2, 5) #the 2 is in the (axis=)1st position
Stacked on axis 2 my array has 3 dimensions and a shape of (5, 5, 2) #the 2 is in the (axis=)2nd position
```

Put another way, stacking adds a dimension along which the arrays are stacked. The axis parameter determines which dimension is created during stacking/along which dimension they are stacked

> What does axis = -1 really mean?

Why does `print("Hello world"[-1])` print "d"?
Or, in other words, if we want to count our dimensions from last to first:

```
for i in range(-3,0):
    print(f"Stacked on axis {i} my array has {np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=i).ndim} dimensions and a shape of {np.stack(cart_indexing, axis=i).shape}")

Stacked on axis -3 my array has 3 dimensions and a shape of (2, 5, 5) #dimension that is third from last
Stacked on axis -2 my array has 3 dimensions and a shape of (5, 2, 5) #dimension that is second from last
Stacked on axis -1 my array has 3 dimensions and a shape of (5, 5, 2) #last dimesnion
```